# parse using nested maps and itemgetter in python

Tags: python, list

I want to map a list of temp1,..tempn with a nested list

```
  list1 = ['temp1', 'temp2', 'temp3', 'temp4']
  list2 = [['30C', '86F', '303K', '545R' ], ['-5.55C', '22F', '267K', '481R' ], ['0', '32F', '273K', '491R'], ['-17C', '0', '256K', '461R']]
```

I want to map like this

```
  temp1   30C  -5.55C   0   -17C
  temp2   86F   22F    32F    0
  temp3   303K  267K   273K  256K
  temp4   545R  481R   491R  461R
```

That is to map 1st term of list1 to nth_1 term of list2 and like that.

like

```
  new_list = [['temp1',['30C','-5.55C', '0', '-17C']], ['temp2', ['86F', '22F', '32F', '0']], ['temp3', ['303K', '267K', '273K', '256K'], ['temp4',['545R', '481R', '491R', '461R']]]
```

I then want to consider each temp and check if that temp_n has a zero in it and then remove the columns which have zero in it

for temp1

```
  temp1   30C  -5.55C   **0**   -17C
  temp2   86F   22F    **32F**    0
  temp3   303K  267K   **273K**  256K
  temp4   545R  481R   **491R**  461R
```

to get

```
  temp1   30C  -5.55C  -17C
  temp2   86F   22F      0
  temp3   303K  267K   256K
  temp4   545R  481R   461R
```

Now my output1 for temp1 should be

```
 output1 = temp1&30C + temp2&86F + temp3&303K + temp4&545R, temp1&-5.55C + temp2&22F + temp3&267K + temp4&481R, temp1&-17C + temp3&256K + temp4&461R
```

(Dont consider temp2&0)

for temp2

```
  temp1   30C  -5.55C   0   **-17C**
  temp2   86F   22F    32F    **0**
  temp3   303K  267K   273K  **256K**
  temp4   545R  481R   491R  **461R**
```

so it becomes

```
   temp1   30C  -5.55C   0   
   temp2   86F   22F    32F   
   temp3   303K  267K   273K  
   temp4   545R  481R   491R
```

Now my output2 for temp2 should be

```
 output2 = temp1&30C + temp2&86F + temp3&303K + temp4&545R, temp1&-5.55C + temp2&22F + temp3&267K + temp4&481R, temp2&32F + temp3&273K + temp4&491R
```

temp3 and temp4 dont have zeros, so their output is

```
   output3 = temp1&30C + temp2&86F + temp3&303K + temp4&545R, temp1&-5.55C + temp2&22F + temp3&267K + temp4&481R, temp2&32F + temp3&273K + temp4&491R, temp1&-17C + temp3&256K + temp4&461R
```

output4 is same as output3.

I tried using maps and itemgetter,but could'nt seem to get it.

```
 new_list = []    
 for temp, i in zip(list1,list2):
    for j in i:
       new_list.append(temp, list2[i][j], list2[i+1][j], list2[i+2][j], list2[len(list2)][j])

  for n in list1:    #create n lists for each temp
      outputlistn = []

  for i in new_list:
      for j in i:
          for k in j:
              if k != 0
                 outputlistn.append(j)
```

I can't figure out how to remove column containing zero.

```
for n in list1:
      outputn = ",".join("+".join("&".join(k)for k in outputlistn))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the sum means in your `outputX` (is it addind integer values, is it concatenating strings?), but assuming you know what to do with them, here is how you can get those 'trimmed' arrays:

```
arr = np.array([list1]+list2).transpose()

for row in arr:
    cols = list(filter(lambda i: row[i] != '0',range(arr.shape[1])))
    trimmed = arr[:, cols]
    # do whatever you need to format your 'sum'
```

Note that you probably don't really need to add `[list1]` to `arr` and transpose but I still include it to match your display... If you want to get rid of them just use:

```
arr = np.array(list2)

for col in range(arr.shape[1]):
    rows = list(filter(lambda i: arr[i,col] != '0',range(arr.shape[0])))
    trimmed = arr[rows]
    # do whatever you need to format your 'sum'
```

EDIT to match your formatting:

```
arr = np.array(list2)

for col in range(arr.shape[1]):
    rows = list(filter(lambda i: arr[i,col] != '0',range(arr.shape[0])))
    trimmed = arr[rows]
    print ", ".join(" + ".join(temp+"&"+k for temp,k in zip(list1,row) if k != '0') for row in trimmed)
    print ""
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Julien Bernu :) It is not sum, I am just joining the results using '&' , '+' and comma. I am not doing any arithmetic operations there

Comment: Your second code does not give me the right answer. Your first code throws me an error for 't'

Comment: the 't' should be 'arr' sorry, I just updated it. What is wrong with the answer?

Comment: I tried your first code. I got my answer as `temp1 temp2 temp3 temp4`                                                                                                                       `-17C  0  256K  461R `

Comment: Well that's just a string formatting problem, I assumed you'd take care of it... see edit.